# Thinkpad X41 hard drive replacement

Tags: hard-drive, thinkpad

I have seen reports that Thinkpad X41 laptops have had problems with replacement drives (internal) larger than 60Gb. Has anyone successfully replaced the hard drive in their X41 with an 80Gb drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news first: The IBM X40/41's are notorious for having a [proprietary connector](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?p=240673#p240673).  The X41's 1.8" drive is not compatible with conventional 1.8" laptop drives, never mind that pickings are slim even at the more common 2.5" size when compared to desktops.  The thread above mentions that you can still jam a 7K100 in there but it will stick out; less than ideal.

The good news is that was 3 years ago and now certain SSD's have arisen that may fit, like the Kingspec SSD.  Considering the stock 4200rpm, I can't think of a wider performance margin.  Be aware that in some cases, a [cloning process is necessary](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?p=505888#p505888)<sup>(1)</sup>:

> - Move original HD to a USB housing (not sure what kind of adapter you'd
>     need for the X40 drive, sorry)
> - Install new HD into internal drive bay
> - Connect USB drive to X40
> - Boot X40 into bootable Acronis or Ghost CD using either a USB CD/DVD
>     drive or an Ultrabase CD/DVD drive
> - Do the cloning
> - Remove the extra drives, reboot into Windows!

Again, not just any SSD will work; the link above references a particular model from Kingspec.

<sup>(1) Credits to tomh009 of the thinkpads.com forum.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't really be a problem.

This isn't really a limitation of the Thinkpad, more of a limitation of what is available - it uses 1.8" hard drives instead of normal laptop 2.5" which are rarer and come in smaller capacities.

Comment: Quite correct, thats why I'm going for 80Gb since it's the largest one I could find. I have seen reports that X41 wont boot on drives larger than 60Gb though, thats why I'm keen to know of any successful upgrades >60Gb.

Comment: It could, potentially, be an artificial limit imposed by IBM. I strongly doubt they would do this though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen one of my friend using it. It should be a-ok.

Note that there is significant hardware compatibility problem for X41 laptops - i see reports of toshiba 80G harddrives not working with it just by casually googling (reference: http://forum.51nb.com/redirect.php?tid=951249&goto=lastpost :: article in simplified chinese you may or may not be able to read it)

thus, see reports of others before buying.